# Regex maxlength per word in textarea - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, textarea

I'm trying a regular expression that allows no more than 17 characters per word in textarea. I have tried couple of expressions but till now no success.

For example Im trying to succeed something like this :

```
ADQQ213323DS2D33S
ADQQ213323DSDDSDA
73721GE276G2E1772
```

Only numbers and letter should be allowed and space or new line.

Regex I have tried :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\n]{17}$
```

Comment: *"I have tried couple of expressions but till now no success."* Care to show them to us?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to write it. Ive just updated the question

Comment: Your regex [works](https://regex101.com/r/DJbVjw/1)

Comment: Yes but when I press enter or space it detects more than 17 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pattern` attribute on the HTML5 `<textarea>` tag is not powerful enough to do what you need to do because you need the `s` flag so that `^` and `$` anchors will also match the start and end of lines. The following regex also uses the `i` flags for case insensitivity:

```
/^\s*([a-z0-9]{1,17}(\s+|$))*$/is
```

1. `^` matches the start of the string or the start of a line
2. `\s*` matches 0 or more white space characters
3. `([a-z0-9]{1,17}` matches 1 to 17 letters or digits
4. `(\s+|$)` matches one or more spaces or the end of the line
5. `*` steps 3 thorugh 5 are repeated 0 or more times
6. `$` matches the end of the line or the end of the line or the end of the string.

The following snippet installs an `onkeyup` handler for the textarea so that after every new character appears in the textarea the contents are tested against the regex and if the test fails the prior contents are restored.

```js
function setupField(field, re)
{
    field.autocomplete = "off";
    field.saveValue = field.value;
    field.onkeyup = function() {
        var v = field.value;
        if (v === '' || re.test(v)) {
            field.saveValue = v;
        }
        else {
            field.value = field.saveValue;
        }
    };
}

function setup()
{
  let regex = /^\s*([a-z0-9]{1,17}(\s+|$))*$/is;
  setupField(document.f.ta, regex);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="setup();">
<form name="f">
   Enter text:<br>
   <textarea name="ta" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```